# Python Script Batch File

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduler

Struggling with what is I am sure a very straight forward problem. I have a scheduled task set up which launches a batch file, which in turn runs a Python script. All is well, however I cannot seem to close the Python shell once the script is finished. The result is lots of open windows.

If this is a Python issue, I have read the best way to close is to do the following:

```
import selenium
import json
import time
import datetime
import sys

from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import timedelta

today = datetime.datetime.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday = yesterday.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/portal/functions/timon/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('http://adventures.timon.is')
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id('tbxNumerstarfsmanns').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('tbxNumerstarfsmanns').send_keys('user')
browser.find_element_by_id('tbxUserLykilord').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('tbxUserLykilord').send_keys('pass')
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit\"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*=reports]").click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Salary administrators").click()
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Punch-in report").click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id('id_fromdate').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('id_fromdate').send_keys(yesterday)
browser.find_element_by_id('id_todate').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('id_todate').send_keys(yesterday)
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=submit]").click()
time.sleep(2)

results = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("table#resultstable td")

columns = [val.text for val in results]

data = json.dumps(columns)

text_file = open("c:/xampp/htdocs/portal/functions/timon/info.txt", "w")
text_file.write(data)
text_file.close()

browser.close()
sys.exit()
```

However this does not work.

Batch file looks like this...

```
start "extractTimon" "C:\xampp\Python36-32\python.exe" C:\xampp\htdocs\portal\functions\timon\extractTimon.py
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If that's all that's in the batch file, schedule python.exe directly instead. If you don't need a console window, use pythonw.exe instead.

Comment: If your script is hung somewhere in `do stuff`, then adding `sys.exit()` at the end isn't a magic incantation to solve the problem. Provide a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: No problem, pasted Python script in it's entirety. Script takes some time to run, though I don't believe it is "hung" anywhere? The browser window closes (as per browser.close at the end) and the text file I am updating gets updated as expected.

Comment: It could be waiting to join a non-daemon thread that was created by selenium. Before exiting, list the available threads with `import threading;`  `print(threading.enumerate())`. Is there more than one active thread?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I am only seeing what I assume (sorry, newbie) is a single "main" thread.

Comment: Try a similar check for multiprocessing: `import multiprocessing;` `print(multiprocessing.active_children())`.

Comment: Also check the list of exit handlers: `import atexit;` `print(atexit._exithandlers)`.